# Finding the Frequency and big O for this code segment

Tags: data-structures, big-o

Can anyone explain how to analyze this code segment?

I can't understand how to get the frequency count for second line.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: this looks like your homework...

Comment: O(n^2) - second loop runs n/2 times...

Comment: What is your background knowledge of big O...

Comment: @NikitaMalyschkin First no it is not my homework,anyway thanks for your great help.

Comment: @WendingPeng I have done few search it is analyzed using Arithmetic series but ican't get it .

Comment: @SMA can you explain to me how did you get it ? thank you yes the answer is O(n^2)

Comment: @diabawii Umm... then you should read more about it. Most CS algorithm courses teach Big O notation in the first lecture, so it won't be hard to find resources about it.

Comment: @WendingPeng thank you for your assist :).

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @DonBranson Thank you , I will do my best to follow the rules and check again before posting.and by the way it is not my homework. thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand `Time Complexity` and `Space complexity` to get a good understanding of analysing code like you have posted above. You can start from [here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/computational-complexity-section-1/)

To briefly describe your code, there are two loops: outer loop and inner loop. The outer loop will run n times. Now, this is how the inner loop will work:
First `j` will be equal to `1`. Then the inner loop will run for `n` times, just like the outer loop. So, `j = 1` and then the control will enter in the inner loop so `x = 1,3,4,6...`. First, `x` will be equal to `1`. Then, `x = x + 2` will make `x = 3`. Then, `x` will be incremented by one and `x` will be equal to `4` and so on.

Once this inner loop finishes, we move onto the outer loop again and `j` will be equal to `2`. Now again control will go back inside the inner loop. so `x = 1,3,4,6...` once again. This will keep on happening until `j = n`.

Then the outer loop will terminate and the control will move out of both these loops.

Comment: Don't forget that `x` is also incremented by 2 after every execution of the inner loop

Comment: Did you mean `x = 1, 3, 5, 7 ...`?

Comment: @AnkitArora thank you for your explanation ,so this means it will be O(n^2) .for example if n =8 ,the outer loop will run 8 times  when the inner loop will run n/2 times for each value of J. Am i correct ?

Comment: @diabawii Yes that is correct. If this answers your questions, please mark this as the right answer.

Comment: @AnkitArora Thank you for your help